# Disabling log on for technical OS X user

Tags: macos, login, boot, user-accounts

I created a technical user that is only used to run a certain service. It doesn't have a home folder or anything else standard. The account also doesn't appear in the `System Preferences... > Accounts` settings, which is good. However it does appear as a possible log in account after startup.

How do I disable or manipulate the list of presented users at startup of OS X?

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day you could set the user ID below 500 and it would automatically be hidden, now it involves a little more work. Open up terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow HiddenUsersList -array-add username
```

You can add multiple users by separating them with spaces. If you have only one other account on the system, it will unfortunately show an "Other" button at the login screen. If you want to make the existence of the account even more hidden, you can remove the button by running this in the terminal.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool FALSE
```

Restart the system to make sure everything gets applied. If you have any problems with it leave a comment and I'll try to help you resolve it.